# What does “altes Haus” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquial

What does *altes Haus* mean?

> Was geht, altes Haus?

Does it mean “What’s up, pal”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **4 – Person, Mensch**
>
> **Gebrauch**
>
> umgangssprachlich scherzhaft
>
> **Beispiele**
>
> er ist ein fideles, gemütliches, gelehrtes Haus
>
> wie gehts, altes Haus (alter Freund)

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *altes Haus* is probably best described as *pal* or *bro*. Someone which needs to a good friend or a guy from your clique you see regularly. I would say a good English translation, which gives you the right feeling is

> [Whaddup, bro!?](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whaddup)

You (maybe) souldn't use it at work, but with your homies it is OK.

Comment: I'd say Altes Haus is more like Old Chap. Bro sounds too much like frat kids, and Altes Haus is more of an older term.

Answer (score 1):

The Great Gatsby says *old chap* in English, and *altes Haus* in at least one German translation that I have read (Johanna Elsworth — 2011).